# Move Sensor data to a different class/activity

Tags: android

I have a simple app, it logs a bunch of sensor/gps data.  The first activity is a mess, and way too long, so i wanted to modularize it.  I want to have 3 modules now:

1. Main Activity
2. Sensor Data (Gyroscope, accelerometer, etc)
3. GPS Data (Position, elevation, etc)

What is the best way for me to go about modularizing this?  I was trying to move some of the Sensor Data out of the original class, and then I noticed that my class needed to extend some `android.content.context` (such as an `Activity`) in order to access the sensor data properly?

Thanks for a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: You don't need to extend `Context` - you can create helper classes and simply pass the `Activity` context into the class constructor or into the various methods using `this` from the `Activity`.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I actually hadn't thought of that.  Is this considered a good practice?

Comment: Good practice is to make consistent classes that will do what they are supposed to do and nothing more. [Careful planning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_programming_practices#Planning_game) is very important and also it is good to have some [predefined rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_programming_practices#Shared_understanding) for coding. Don't let it [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: @MasterGberry : As far as "good practice" is concerned, yes and no is the answer. As long as you design your helper classes correctly then it is fine and it is something that may people do and, indeed, there are various Android classes which require a `Context` parameter. Avoid memory leaks and use the right `Context` (either Application context or Activity context) at the right time and it'll be fine.

Comment: @Squonk Sounds good :) Working for me at the moment, if you want to post a quick answer, I will give you the accepted answer as you deserve.  Thanks!

Comment: @MasterGberry : Answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comments on the original question...

You don't need to extend `Context` - you can create helper classes and simply pass the `Activity` `Context` into the class constructor or into the various methods using `this` from the `Activity`.

As long as you design your helper classes correctly then it is fine and it is something that many people do and, indeed, there are various Android classes which require a `Context` parameter. Avoid memory leaks and use the right `Context`.

Sometimes using the application `Context` might be better as it is persistent for the life-time of all application components. It is, however, only a partial context in that certain things won't work with it (some UI-related tasks, for example). Otherwise using the `Activity` `Context` is fine as long as nothing holds a permanent reference to it (which can cause memory leaks if the `Activity` is destroyed.